# Table Valued Function in SQL Data Tools 2012 won't publish

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I want to create a Table Valued Function with SQL Data Tools but it won't publish.
I have a DB with columns:

```
Id(bigint), Voornaam (Nchar(50)), Naam (Nchar(50)), AantalPintjes (bigint)
```

My code will build successfully, but when I want to publish, I get the error:

> "Executing publish script on Database 'bier' : An error Occured while the batch was being executed.

In the published SQL I got a script execution error:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1
    FROM [dbo].[tbl_BierDrinkers])
RAISERROR (N'Rows were detected. The schema update is terminating because data loss might occur.', 16, 127)
    WITH NOWAIT;
```

And here's my C# code:

```
public class Bierdrinkers
{
    public SqlInt64 Id { get; set; }
    public SqlString Naam { get; set; }
    public SqlString Voornaam { get; set; }
    public SqlInt64 AantalPintjes { get; set; }

    public Bierdrinkers()
    {

    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Convert.ToString(Naam) + " : (aantal pintjes: " + Convert.ToInt64(AantalPintjes) + " )";
    }


    [SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read,FillRowMethodName = "VentileerRijen", TableDefinition = "Id bigint,Naam nchar(50), Voornaam nchar(10), AantalPintjes bigint")]
    public static IEnumerable OphalenData()
    {
        List<Bierdrinkers> res = new List<Bierdrinkers>();
       /* res.Add(new Bierdrinkers() { AantalPintjes = 1, Id = 1, Naam = "a", Voornaam = "b" });
         return res;*/


        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            // Use the connection

            string SQL = "Select * from tbl_BierDrinkers";
            SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(SQL, connection);

            SqlDataReader datareader = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
            while (datareader.Read())
            {
                Bierdrinkers bd = new Bierdrinkers();
                bd.Id = Convert.ToInt32(datareader["Id"]);
                bd.Naam = datareader["Naam"].ToString();
                bd.Voornaam = datareader["Voornaam"].ToString();
                bd.AantalPintjes = Convert.ToInt32(datareader["AantalPintjes"]); ;
                res.Add(bd);
                Console.WriteLine(bd);
            }
            return res;
        }
    }

    public static void VentileerRijen(object obd, out SqlInt64 Id, out SqlString Naam, out SqlString Voornaam, out SqlInt64 AantalPintjes)
    {
        Bierdrinkers bd = obd as Bierdrinkers;
        Id = bd.Id;
        Naam = bd.Naam;
        Voornaam = bd.Voornaam;
        AantalPintjes = bd.AantalPintjes;
    }
}
```

I also tried a startup script, but it made no difference:

```
use Bier;
select * from OphalenData();
```

Comment: From the error message it looks as though the publish is also trying to replace the definition of `tbl_BierDrinkers` and then backing out as that already contains rows.

Comment: What type of publication are you creating (i.e., snapshot, transactional, transactional with updatable subscriptions, or merge)?